# what's the rule for tense consistency within a sentence?

Tags: tenses

I have a doubt regarding tense consistency within the same sentence.
Which one between these two sentences is correct?

A - when he comes out of the house, a storm blows all over the city.
B - when he comes out of the house, a storm is blowing all over the city.

Or in this instance

A - a man comes out of the house, takes his time to check the surroundings.
B - a man comes out of the house, taking his time to check the surroundings.

When, as a general rule, is it proper to use a continuous in the second part of the sentence?

Comment: A storm is something that goes on for some time; it isn't a single incident like a man walking out of a house. You need the continuous tense.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In this case, that's what I thought too, but, perhaps, it was a bad example. I will edit the post to make it clearer.

Comment: Your first two mean different things.  The second "A" is lacking a conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

> When, as a general rule, is it proper to use a continuous in the second part of the sentence?

The continuous form is not specific to the "first part" or "second part" of a sentence. The continuous form has a specific function:

The continuous form of the verb indicates an action that is/was/will be **(i)** incomplete and **(ii)** in progress **(iii)** at the time that is being referred to. Thus the action has started but it has not yet finished.

-> *I will be/am/was/have been/had been riding a bike* = *I will be/am/was/have been/had been* in the process of *riding a bike but have not yet finished riding the bike* at the time I am referring to.

The continuous form used to be known as “the imperfect”: It was called “imperfect” because the action had not been “perfected” i.e. it had not finished.

OED

> 5. *Grammar*. **Applied to a tense which denotes action going on but not completed; usually to the past tense of incomplete or progressive action.**
>
> 1871 H. J. Roby Gram. Latin Lang. §549 Three [tenses] denoting incomplete action; the Present, Future, and Imperfect (sometimes called respectively, present imperfect, future imperfect, past imperfect).

Comment: what if the continuous indicates a way the action is performed? such as 'he checks out the house, walking from to room' would that be correct instead of 'he checks out the house and walks from room to room'?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.